# Count files made by given user in Centos

Tags: file, count, find, ls, file-ownership

My sessions directory is very large and I would like to count how many files are made by each separate user (each domain).

Is there an option (with `ls` maybe) to count (not to list) total files made by a given user ?

I know that `ls -alh dir_name` lists all files and user is on one of the columns.

And also that this counts all files: `ls -1 dir_name | wc -l`

Maybe command can be adjusted to do a search on the column containig the username, and then count the results?

Comment: quick and dirty ... you can filter the `ls -alh dir_name` results with `| grep username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the `username`, this should work for you.

```
find dir_name -type f -user 'username' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
 ls -alh dir_name | awk -F " " '{ print $3;}' | sort | uniq -c
```

is pretty close to what you want.